# How to create a new matrix with a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am a newbie. I have problem.
I have 20 (1x100) different named vectors. I want to combine these vectors to create a 20x100 matrix with a for loop.
There are the examples of vectors.

```
namelist=["First","B","New"]
First = [1:100]
B = [1:2:200]
New = [4:4:400]
for i = 1: length(namelist)
    new_database(i,1:end) = namelist{i}
end
```

But, when I want to try this I saw "The end operator must be used within an array index expression." error.
I know I can do same thing with this:
"new_database= [First;B;New]"

but i want to do this with a for loop.
Would you help me how can fix this error? or Would you explain me how can do this?

Comment: What you need to do given this setup is something more like `new_database(i,:) = eval([namelist{i}, ';']);`. What you *should* do is avoid dynamic variable naming and not put yourself in a position where this is required in the first place! Please see [MathWorks: Evading Eval](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)

Comment: @Wolfie
Thank you for your answer!
Also, I saw this post https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

> `new_database(i,1:end) = namelist{i}`

the curly braces are used with cells, exclusively and there is no need to use range indexing as you do (i, 1:end)

Generally, it is better practice to assign character arrays or strings to cells.

One question, what are you doing with the 'First', 'New' and 'B' ranges arrays?

Something like:

```
namelist=["First","B","New"]

First = [1:100];
B = [1:2:200];
New = [4:4:400];

new_database = cell(1, length(namelist));

for i = 1: length(namelist)   % or length(new_database)
    new_database{i} = namelist(i)
end
```

which generates this output:

[image]

EDIT: My apologies, now I see what you are trying to accomplish. You are building a database from a series of arrays, correct?

Following my previous response, you must consider some points:

1 Your new_database should be square. Regardless of the dimensions of the arrays you are passing to it, if you form a cell from them, you will invariably have empty cells if no data is passed to those rows or columns

2 In some cases, you don't need to use for-loops, where simple indexing might suffice your case problem. Consider the following example using `cellstr`:

```
titles = ["Position", "Fruits", "Mythical creatures"] 
A = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
B = ["Apple", "Banana", "Durian"];
C = ["Dragon", "Cat", "Hamster"];

db = cell(4, 3);

db(1,:) = cellstr(titles)
db(2:end,1) = cellstr(A)
db(2:end,2) = cellstr(B)
db(2:end,3) = cellstr(C)
```

which generates this output:

[image]

Comment: Daniel, you are right! I was trying to create a database from the data I had. Thank you for your response!